# What should I do to connect to an already running flask instance using flask-script and click inside a terminal in ubuntu

Tags: python, flask, click, flask-script

I want to be able to connect to an already running instance of a flask application inside ubuntu terminal. I've tried flask-script and click, but the problem is when I execute the "flask shell" command, it starts a new instance of the application and I'm unable to use the already running instance, any idea?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by `connecting`?

Comment: Why do you need to connect to already running flask instance. Also, how are you running that flask instance? uwsgi?

Comment: @dmigo I mean the ability to execute different services of the running application in the flask shell. to be able to do stuffs like reloading configs and more.

Comment: @SujanAdiga yeah, it's behind uwsgi in production.

Comment: You can explore --pyshell option in uwsgi.